# Output the same amount of rows as asterisks using for-loop

Tags: python-3.x

I'm taking a Python class at the library, I'm a total beginner to coding, and I'm having trouble with this one assignment. Using a for-loop, it asks us to "write a program that reads in n, where n is a number from 2 to 10. The program should output n rows of asterisks, where the number of asterisks is equal to the row number." Furthermore, if n = "stop", it should print "No stars!"

For example, where n = 4:

```
*
**
***
****
```

I know how to ask for input. I can make it print asterisks. I just can't figure out how to make it so that it only prints the amount of rows and asterisks the user inputs. I hope I described this alright. I also can't make it print "No stars!" if I input "stop".

```
n = input ("Enter a number between 2 and 10: ")

for n in range (1, 11):
    print (n * "*")

if n == "stop":
    print ("No stars!")
```

Comment: Step 1: Move the last if-statement above the loop, then step 2: figure out how to convert from a text (which will be what the user types in, stored in `n`) to a number which you can use as the limit of your loop (in place of 11).

Answer (score 0):

I think the main misunderstanding that you are having is with the for loop.

When you do a for x in y it takes each part of y and runs the body of the for loop with that part of y being assigned to x. In your case, its a range so each "part" of the range is a number which is counting up the the upper bound of the range.

So for each iteration of the loop n = 1, the body is run, n = 2, the body is run, ... and so on.

So to fix this make the upper bound of the range equal to n+1.

```
n = input ("Enter a number between 2 and 10: ")

if n == "stop":
    print("No starts!")
try:
    n = int(n)
    if n>=2 and n<=10:
        for x in range (1, n+1):
            print (x * "*")

except:
    print("invalid input")
```

Comment: I tried this and it executed, but there was no output. I also haven’t learned “isinstance” yet. Is there another way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: @jamey updated it assuming you have used try / except

Answer (score 0):

Completing the other answer, user input is `string` type and should be converted to `integer` for any arithmetic or Boolean operation:

```
n = input ("Enter a number between 2 and 10: ")

if n == "stop":
    print("No starts!")
elif 2 <= int(n) <=10:
    for x in range (1, int(n)):
        print (x * "*")
else:
    print("Number is out or range")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are taking input as a string and storing it in n. Then you use n again as the integer iterator in the for loop. So change the 'n' to something else in for loop.

The range is also hardcoded: the first argument is the start value, the second is the stop. So to use a variable in your code would be range(1, n)

```
str_n = input("Enter a number between 2 and 10: ")
n = int(str_n)    # See NOTE, but basically takes the string and turns into an int
for i in range(1, n+1): # have to store loop iterator in new variable
    print(i * "*")
```

to replace

```
n = input ("Enter a number between 2 and 10: ") # this stores a string in n

for n in range (1, 11):                         # this overwrites n to an int
    print (n * "*")
```

NOTE: This is assuming (which isn't good) that the user will actually input an integer. If they don't, it will throw a ValueError

As for the "No stars" on "stop". Where is this 'stop' coming from? Unless the user input a pretty large number there isn't going to be any time to 'command interrupt'(not sure exact terminology in Python, but think CTRL-C or such for terminals). But to achieve the "No stars" at the end of the loop:

```
    print(i * "*")
print("No stars!")
```

Taking a bigger leap and saying you build a list the length of user input(so n=4)

```
nList = ['','','','','stop']
for i in range(0, len(nList)-1):
    if nList[i] == 'stop':
        break
    else:
        print((i+1) * "*")
```

The list would have to be built, which is beyond the scope of question, but that would be the basic layout.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone! I took everyone’s feedback into consideration, and this is my final product (I even accounted for ValueError, as one of you mentioned):

n = input ("Enter a number between 2 and 10: ")

try:
    if n == "stop":
        print ("No stars!")

```
elif 2 <= int(n) <=10:
    for x in range (1, int (n)+ 1):
        print (x * "*")

else:
    print ("Number is out of range.")
```

except ValueError:
        print ("Enter a number!")

(For some reason, the first and last part isn’t appearing properly in the box, but the program does work.)